# How to make an app to follow theme of the phone?

Tags: android, android-theme

I made my Hello World app, 3 widgets, no styling at all. I set minimum SDK for 2.1, I test my app on Android 2.3. When I design my app (in Eclipse) and when I run it I have black text on white.

The problem is the phone theme (it is default theme) is light text on black.

Since my main widget is `RelativeLayout` I tried to specify a theme for it as `?android:style/Theme` but the effect was the same as previously.

So how to make an app which will follow the phone theme exactly? I mean I don't want to make styling on my own at all, if the theme is red text on pink, so be it, my app should follow this. I would not like to use any hardcoded values (like "fixed white on fixed black" because those might work for me, and not somebody else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! ;-) I assume here you use Eclipse -- go to your Manifest, Application tab, Theme editbox. There is a value entered there (not by me), delete it, and voila -- now your app follows the phone theme.

**Tested only on one phone** -- running Android 2.3. For further reference please comment this answer if you successfully tested it on another Android version.